# How to retain back arrow in toolbar even drawer is closed or open state?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

In toolbar always need to be retained the back arrow instead of showing three horizontal line menu.

when navigation drawer is closed - horizontal line menu

when navigation drawer is opened - Back arrow

```
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
            }
```

By using above one code I can be able to stop the animation.

How to always keep back arrow in toolbar?

Comment: try making it visible something like menu.findItem(R.id.action_back).setVisible(true);

Comment: @anup where to use your suggestion?

Comment: inside your  onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

By using above code achieved my goal.

Answer (score 1):

> Use this code in onCreate method and after setContentView(). It helped me.

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT )
        {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY );
        }
```